# Fallback service spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, failover, fallback

We execute run a API to download a groups files with api below:
curl -X POST localhost:port/manager/createTask
Rest API: (manager)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/manager")
public class ClusterResource {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;
    @PostMapping("/createTask")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity doTasks() throws Exception {
        myService.doTask();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

MyService class:

```
@Service
public class MyService
    private String templateFileName = "example";
    @Autowired
    private DownloadService downloadService;
    @Async
    public ResponseTaskDto doTasks() throws Exception {
         ResponseTaskDto result = new ResponseTaskDto();
         int downloadFlag;
         int taskFlag;
         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
             if (doTask(i)) {
                 downloadFlag |= i; // downloaded file
                 result.setDownloadFlag(downloadFlag);
                 // execute some code to move file downloaded to correct location
                 // Execute setup proxy network, rollout services use resource file
                 taskFlag |= i; // setup done task
                 result.setTaskFlag(taskFlag);
             }
         }
         return clusterResult;
    }
    private boolen doTask(int number) throws Exception {
        String file = new String(templateFileName + number + ".mp4");
        try {
            downloadService.downloadFile(file);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // download service work well. can not here
            //throw ex;
            return false; // download filed: invalid url, ...
        }
        return true;
    }
   public class ResponseTaskDto {
        int downloadFlag;
        int taskFlag;
        public void setDownloadFlag(int flag) {
            this.downloadFlag = flag;
        }
        public int getDownloadFlag() {
            return this.downloadFlag;
        }
        public void setTaskFlag(int flag) {
            this.taskFlag = flag;
        }
        public int getTaskFlag() {
            return this.taskFlag;
        }
   }
}
```

DownloadService class:

```
@FeignClient(value = "http://downloader")
public interface DownloadService {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/downloader/api/", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    void downloadFile(@PathVariable("file") String fileName);
}
```

we are public 2 microservice of manager as Manager1, Manager2
when api called then assumed: assume it will be consumed by the manager1.

If the microservice manager1 was crashed when receiving too much request tasks.

**Question :**
How to manager2 known the progress services manager1 to continue createTask ?
Example: Manager1 has done  3 steps (download and setup task) before its crashed.

Answer (score 0):

You should try ribbon load balancing to balance between Manager1 and Manager2 instances of the service. Also there is no way that manager2 would be able to pickup manager1's tasks in between.